# Display a uiview object in a window

Tags: objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0

hi am trying to display a uiview class object in the window but the thing is that its not being displayed don't know for what reason am not able to sort out please do help me out, here's my code

```
    @interface Myview : UIViewController {


    UIView *move_view;

    UIButton *btn;



}


@end




#import "Myview.h"


@implementation Myview

 // The designated initializer.  Override if you create the controller programmatically and want to perform customization that is not appropriate for viewDidLoad.
- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {

        // Custom initialization
        [move_view setFrame:CGRectMake(41, 91, 64, 82)];
        [move_view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];


        btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(113, 298, 72, 37)];
        [btn setTitle:@"Move" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(moveaview) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    }
    return self;
}



// Implement loadView to create a view hierarchy programmatically, without using a nib.
- (void)loadView {

    [super loadView];
    [self.view addSubview:move_view];
    [self.view addSubview:btn];
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have to alloc+initialize the view in the init method. Also, are you sure you have alloc+init correctly the UIViewController and attached to the AppDelegate window?
Some other remarks:

- Do not call MyView a UIViewController subclass, the code is less understandable
- If you are loading the Controller from a NIB/XIB you'd better ovverrid the method `- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil`

Comment: Thanks man this work load was seriously killing me 
thank u for the help i just can't believe it i skipped that part thanks a lot rano

Comment: @Radix, glad it helped. Try to use Interface Builder for little task like this, it will manage the IBOutlets alloc and init properly